# How to brace boiler exhaust snorkels?

Tags: hvac

I have PVC exhaust pipes coming out of a wall.  The wall is covered in vinyl siding.  The pipes are 3.5 inches OD and run a few feet vertically along the wall (snorkels).  One is 3-4 inches from the siding and the other 5-6 inches.

I need to brace these pipes to the wall to steady them.  The brace will not support the full weight, the snorkels already stand up on their own.  What is a good way to do this?  My fallback is large split-ring pipe hangers but it seems like there should be a better way.  For one thing these would be a pain to get into position with the pipes already in place.  Something like a chimney support bracket could work but I don't see any small enough.

[image]

Comment: Would you be against simply fastening a piece of PT wood to the siding (basically as a spacer), and attaching a plain old pipe strap around the pipe, to the wood?

Comment: @Huesmann I had that thought but I'd like something a bit more nice looking.

Comment: So instead of PT wood, get some siding accessories, like a mounting block or similar?  Or buy some stainless steel or galvanized strapping and roll your own mounts?

Comment: @Huesmann How is a mounting block going to help?  The pipe going into the wall is already trimmed with a mounting block.  I was thinking just getting some stainless steel and bending it into the right shape might be my best bet.

Comment: A mounting block to use as a spacer since you don't like PT.

Comment: @Huesmann Sounds bulky.  I'm leaning towards getting some stainless steel sheet and trying to fabricate a bracket like the ones in the picture above.